# Как проверить, что файл с таким именем уже существует в директории bash?

Tags: bash

Как проверить, что файл с таким именем уже существует в директории bash?
Допустим, я копирую следующие файлы somedir/file.txt, somedir/somedir2/file.txt в resultdir
Мне нужно скопировать именно первый файл, а так как второй совпадает с первым по имени, то его мне нельзя копировать. Как реализовать проверку, что в resultdir уже есть файл с названием file.txt?

Comment: `test -e файл && echo существует`. но вообще прямой ответ: не копируйте второй файл, копируйте только первый, ни к чему проверять наличие файла, который вы только что сами и скопировали.

Comment: `cp --help`, там есть параметр `-n, --no-clobber` *не перезаписывать существующий файл (отменяет ранее указанный ключ -i)*. Возможно это то, что нужно